# Semantic UI Dropdown 'setup menu' fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to change values of semantic dropdown by using `setup menu(values)` method, but it fails when I use `useLabels: false`.

Ex. without `useLabels: false`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    //useLabels: false,
    onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
      console.clear();
      console.log(value);
    }
  });




  $('.ui.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#select').dropdown('setup menu', {
      values: [{
          name: 'Alaska',
          value: 'AK'
        },
        {
          name: 'Arizona',
          value: 'AZ'
        },
        {
          name: 'Arkansas',
          value: 'AR'
        },
        {
          name: 'California',
          value: 'CA'
        }
      ]
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>


<select name="gender" class="ui  dropdown" multiple id="select">
  <option value="">Gender</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<button class="ui button" type="button">Reset values</button>
```

---

Ex. with `useLabels: false`

The problem is, that is shows that it selects value but actually does not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    useLabels: false,
    onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
      console.clear();
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
  $('.ui.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#select').dropdown('setup menu', {
      values: [{
          name: 'Alaska',
          value: 'AK'
        },
        {
          name: 'Arizona',
          value: 'AZ'
        },
        {
          name: 'Arkansas',
          value: 'AR'
        },
        {
          name: 'California',
          value: 'CA'
        }
      ]
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>


<select name="gender" class="ui  dropdown" multiple id="select">
  <option value="">Gender</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<button class="ui button" type="button">Reset values</button>
```

**Or maybe problem is something else, but whatever it is I'm not getting multiple values (Array of chosen values).**

Any help will be appreciated.

**Note:** I'm using `.net` sever controls for `select`, therefore I cannot use `div` structured dropdown

Ex.

```
@Html.DropDownList("", new { 
   @id = "ddPage", 
   @class="ui fluid dropdown search", 
   @multiple="" 
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this snippet, i tried various ways, especially the documented methods, but nothing seemed to work... but if you try a more javascript/jQuery based approach, you can destroy the dropdown, reconstruct the select element with either jQuery or plain javascript and then reinitialize the dropdown, i also added a `set placeholder text`call, i tried inserting an empty option but didn't made the trick, so i used that function instead...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
        //useLabels: false,
        onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
            console.clear();
            console.log(value);
        }
    });
    
    
    $('.ui.button').on('click', function() {
        
        $('#select').dropdown("clear"); // clear dropdown
        $('#select').html(""); // Empty the select
        $('#select').dropdown("destroy"); // Destroy dropdown
        $('#select').dropdown("set placeholder text", 'New Placeholder'); // Set new placeholder
        
        var selectValues = { "AK": "Alaska", "AZ": "Arizona", "CA": "California" }; // define new values
        // populate select
        $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
            $('#select')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",key)
            .text(value)); 
        });
        
        // call your original dropdown definition again
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
            //useLabels: false,
            onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
                console.clear();
                console.log(value);
            }
        });

        console.clear(); // CLEAR CONSOLE
        console.log($('#select').dropdown('get value'));  // GET CURRENT SELECTED VALUE WHICH SHOULD BE NULL

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>


<select name="gender" class="ui  dropdown" multiple id="select">
  <option value="">Gender</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<button class="ui button" type="button">Reset values</button>
```

Comment: Though this approach will work but I need short code, I have plenty of dropdown in my application, and I don't want this long script for a small thing, Thank You Btw

Comment: why not just wrap the logic on a function?

Comment: You code wasn't working properly in my condition so I had to made some changes, though I had same program in my mind but as a last option. thank you for the answer.

Comment: I really don’t like this kind of workarounds but I like semantic more than other css frameworks, especially the drop downs. Hope they fix this cause it should work as you expected in the beginning

Answer (score 2):

3 things:

1. The CDN seems to be outdated. I found the latest while looking at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4029) and clicking on the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb7c5dkz/) right at the end.
2. In the latest version, you no longer need to use `'setup menu'` to update the select.
3. It had nothing to do with `useLabels`. The problem that you're facing seems solvable only when I created a dropdown in the format shown in the [Examples](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/examples).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    //useLabels: false,
    onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
      console.clear();
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
  $('.ui.button').on('click', function() {
    $('#select').dropdown({
      useLabels : false,
      onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
        console.clear();
        console.log(value);
      },
      values: [{
          name: 'Alaska',
          value: 'AK'
        },
        {
          name: 'Arizona',
          value: 'AZ'
        },
        {
          name: 'Arkansas',
          value: 'AR'
        },
        {
          name: 'California',
          value: 'CA'
        }
      ]
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/next/dist/semantic.js"></script>



<button class="ui button" type="button">Reset values</button>


<div id="select" class="ui fluid multiple special selection dropdown">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="default text">Select Country</div>
<div class="menu">
<div class="item" data-value="af"><i class="af flag"></i>Afghanistan</div>
<div class="item" data-value="ad"><i class="af flag"></i>ad</div>
<div class="item" data-value="as"><i class="af flag"></i>as</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working with `select`, and I can't use `div` structured dropdown, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/go4e8uvn/335/)

Comment: Yes, exactly... I tried a lot to solve your problem using `select` only, but it doesn't seem to work. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I tried too with `select`, btw now I have mentioned it in question.

Comment: This was a good idea but as I mentioned I was bound to use `select` that's why I'm accepting above answer, thank you for your time.